# Anylogic - Getting Resource Pool from a seized Resource

Tags: java, anylogic

I have a Service block which can seize a resource from one of two Resource Pools.  At the "On seize unit" section of Actions in that block I'd like to determine which Resource Pool the agent came from.

I tried to create a bespoke agent type for the Resource Pools that could have a variable attached which I could then read via something like "unit.MySpecies" but get the "MySpecies cannot be resolved or is not a field".

My Java/AnyLogic skills are pretty basic, so any help is appreciated.  I saw the answer for getting individual resources utilisation, but I'm hoping this question is an order of magnitude simpler and is just a case of the right words and grammar.

Answer (score 1):

You must use Java properly, the error suggests some wrong format:

1. your variable must be of type "ResourcePool", see screen below
2. you must set it correctly in the resource pool's "on seize" as
3. in the Service "On seize unit" code box, you must access it properly. In my case it would look like `unit.myPool`.

Maybe you are also writing your code wrong in the on seize. If you want to check where the resource comes from, make sure it looks like:

```
if (unit.myPool.equals(myResourcePool)...
```

Where "myResourcePool" is the actual name of the resource pool.

[image]

Comment: Ideally, I would prefer to not have to create a bespoke agent.  Is there an inherent property of unit I can use, in the "On seize unit" box to get it's pool name?  Like unit.getPoolName() if it existed.

Comment: Actually you can do at least part of what you want: If you define and use a custom resource type (Create from the AnyLogic palette module "Process Modeling Library / Resource Type"), then this Type will offer you automatically the function "resourcePool() - Returns the ResourcePool block this unit belongs to". You can access it like this then: ((MyResource)unit).resourcePool() with MyResource being your custom resource type. So at least you do not have to add an additional field "myPool", but you wont come around creating your own Resource Type...