# AnyLogic - Identify seized ResourcePool

Tags: java, anylogic

I am modeling a service process in AnyLogic thorugh hybrid simulation (DES + Agent based).
In this process, I have different resourcePools, one for each employee available in the process. What I would like to knwo, is if I can get, through an AnyLogic function, the ResourcePool currently used by the seize block.The reason why I am needing this information is because then, by using a funcition, I will assign different delays based on the resourcePool seized (e.g., 10 minutes is is rpA, 15 minutes if it is rpB).
I attach a shot example to show my problem.
Let's suppose this is my process:

[image: Process]

I tried to follow the example shown in this post [OtherQuestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56579324/anylogic-getting-resource-pool-from-a-seized-resource)

Thus, I created a variable myPool

[image: myPool]

To be used in the seize and module

[image: seize]

and in the resourcePool

[image: rp]

But I am constantly receiving errors when compiling the model (e.g., "The method myPool() is undefined for the type Main" in the rpA and rpB, and "The method myPool() is undefined for the type Main" in the seize.

My java skills are really basic so I am not really understading how to write the code I need in this question [OtherQuestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56579324/anylogic-getting-resource-pool-from-a-seized-resource) to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before providing an answer, here is an important piece of background knowledge: everything in AnyLogic is an [Agent](https://anylogic.help/api/com/anylogic/engine/Agent.html). The thing going through the **Delay**, the **ResourceUnit**, the **Delay** and **ResourcePool** themselves are all instances of [Agent](https://anylogic.help/api/com/anylogic/engine/Agent.html).

Knowing that, here is one way to do get delay time based on which resource pool was used:

```java
double delayTime = (agent.resourceUnitOfPool​(rpA) != null)? 10.0 : 20:0;
```

The above statement uses a ternary expression in Java. This means that first `agent.resourceUnitOfPool(rpA)` is evaluated. That method "returns the first occurrence of resource unit of a given pool among the seized resource units, or null if not found.", meaning that:

- if *rpA* was used then the value returned will be not null,
- otherwise if *rpB* was used then the value returned will be null.

However, this isn't a good approach. It will work with this model but will likely be inadequate should you need to change the model in the future.

A good approach would be to create resource unit type and specify the delay time as unit property. Instructions on how to make custom resource units can be found [here](https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/resource-type.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would this be valid even with three or more resourcePools?

Comment: For multiple pools, the approach should be based on multiple if statements: `if (agent.resourceUnitsOfPool(rpA) != null) {} else if (agent.resourceUnitsOfPool(rpB) != null) {} else if (... etc.`. Again, a better approach is to do it via properties of resource units or agents themselves.